# How to echo the contents of a function in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

I am using WP mail to send out an email. I have 2 different versions of hte email that I wish to send based on a particular value. The code below is self expalnitory.

```
function implement_ajax_apartmentsearchemail() {



    if ( ($_POST['email']) ) {
        //get the correct page ID
        $to = ($_POST['email']);
        $name = ($_POST['name']);
        $subject = 'Our Recommendations.';
        $postidstring = ($_POST['postidstring']);   
        $reseller = ($_POST['reseller']);   

        if ($reseller == '') {
            $message = emailcontentscp($postidstring, $name);
        } else {
            $message = emailcontentreseller($postidstring, $reseller, $name);
        }            

        $subject = 'Our Recommendations';
        $headers = "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\n";
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
        $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n";
        $headers .= "From: Serviced City Pads  <bookings@citypadsmail.com>\n";    
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);   

        die();
    }


}   

add_action('wp_ajax_apartmentsearchemail', 'implement_ajax_apartmentsearchemail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_apartmentsearchemail', 'implement_ajax_apartmentsearchemail');
```

I am trying to check if the $reseller variable is true or not, if it is then run the reseller mail template and if not, then run the normal SCP mail template.

My condition works to the point where I am returning the correct email template in the console however, when I dump the $message variable it comes back with nothing.

My functions are laid out as follows in different files.

```
function emailcontentscp($postidstring, $name) {
 //wp query to get some posts in a nice looking layout

 //loop start
     <div id="post-entry">some content</div>
 //loop end resetpostdata();

 //there is no return() here.  
}
```

Comment: Are you using `return` in `emailcontentscp()` with the result you want?

Comment: is $_POST['reseller'] set?

Comment: I tried the conditional check without the functions and just added some text and the mail worked both with and without the reseller option being posted. 
In addition, no i am not using return in the function. 
Ill update the function above to give you a better idea of what Ive got.

Comment: Well… use `return`, not `echo` (or whatever you're using).

Comment: Where would I add the return;. After the function or at the end of it. Sorry my PHP skills are still growing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the return value of a function and assigning it to `$message`, the function needs to `return` something. Instead of *outputting* the HTML, store it in a variable and `return` it:

```
function emailcontentscp($postidstring, $name) {
    $template = '<div ...>';

    foreach (...) {
        $template .= '<li ...>';
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. Will my query work inside this variable though. 
It would literally look like $template = '<div>loop</div>';

Comment: Well, no, that's why I'm demonstrating how to *append* to `$template` inside a loop.